# JPA2 EntityManager is null

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, jsf-2, persistence

Code is here: http://github.com/knownasilya/Ambience

I'm testing persistence through my `index.xhtml` and in my Admin class I instantiate the EntityManager with the `@PersistenceContext` annotation. Every time I run this example I get NPE at `em.persist(another);`.

I have the `persistence.xml` setup with the same connection information as my local db configuration in Eclipse. How can I find out where the error is?

**Edit** Here are the relavent files.

Index.xhtml https://github.com/knownasilya/Ambience/blob/master/g5.ambience/WebContent/index.xhtml

Admin.java https://github.com/knownasilya/Ambience/blob/master/g5.ambience/src/g5/ambience/user/admin/model/Admin.java

persistence.xml
https://github.com/knownasilya/Ambience/blob/master/g5.ambience/src/META-INF/persistence.xml

**EDIT2** I created a UserDAO, but I still get a NPE when I try creating the EntityManager specifically on line 24

```
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
```

With this error `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at g5.ambience.user.UserDAO.<init>(UserDAO.java:24)`

UserDAO.java https://github.com/knownasilya/Ambience/blob/master/g5.ambience/src/g5/ambience/user/UserDAO.java

**EDIT3** I now have 3 layers of abstraction/encapsulation. The model (getters/setters for persistence), the business logic, and the view logic.

I have my entity factory here: http://bit.ly/HV4d11, and that's an application scoped managed bean. Then I have the ManagedUserBean http://bit.ly/In19rX which still gives me a NPE when I invoke `getUserByUsername` method through UserView http://bit.ly/In1ta6  (session scoped). Still no luck, the error is on the EntityManager creation, here is my stackTrace: http://pastie.org/3814236

Comment: Why is your DAO extending from an Entity class? Where is your persistence.xml file? You really need to come up with an SSCCE because not alot of people are going to crawl through your repo looking for all the relevant classes.

Comment: To the first sentence: This is because I use one table for the superclass and all of its subclasses with a discriminator column.

Comment: I think it's not possible to inject an entity manager into an entity.

Comment: @jabu.10245 - you are very correct, infact you cannot inject at all into an entity because their lifecycle is not managed by the application container.

Comment: So would I have to use EntityManagerFactory to create a new EntityManager?

Comment: @Knownasilya - you should create a real DAO class. Though some argue against it's usefulness I think you will find that managing your entity manager becomes much simpler with one.

Comment: Or do I need to create an implementation class and add the EntityManager to that class?

Comment: @Knownasilya - I tend to use one 'session' class that has a static to an EntityManagerFactory. That static is then used by all sessions for the whole of the application and all logged in users. Every Entity has it's manager class that has the entityManager, and every Entity is nothing more then fiels and getters/setters. Sometimes a small helper method like getRemainingAmount() if startAmount and paidAmount are already available.

Comment: > Every Entity has it's manager class that has the entityManager


Does the mean they automatically have it, or would I have to create/inject it?

Comment: @jabu.10245 you can inject an entity with the entity manager. Its called the Active Record Pattern. That is what Spring Roo does with (at)Configurable and AspectJ (so yes in ordinary Java you cannot do it with out some nastiness).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UserDAO needs to be a EJB bean e.g. @Stateless to use @PersistenceContext annotation.
Good design pattern is to create two layers

- Backing beans - managed beans for UI, you use them in XHTML.
- Service layer, or DAO as you call it - stateless beans that implement basic business logic

You decide what is business logic and what is UI related logic.

If you use JEE6 CDI solution, you won't need to declare managed beans in faces-config.xml

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have confused the "Active Record" pattern with the "DAO" pattern.

If you want to use the "Active Record" pattern in Java your best option is to use [Spring Roo](http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/architecture.html#architecture-dao) or the Play framework (< 2.0).

Otherwise you will want to follow the the traditional DAO + Service pattern (I believe Roo 1.2.1 now supports this pattern).

*EDIT: After circling back to this question I seriously recommend you use Spring Roo just so you can see how the different design patterns work since Roo now supports both. Also it will setup the entity manager correctly among many other things. You don't have to use Roo in the long run. Your just going to look at the scaffolding code to learn the correct way.*

Comment: I'm having trouble changing the server to Tomcat7 (from Tomcat6) and I get the following error when ever I try to run my application vie `mvn tomcat:run` or `mvn jetty:run-exploded` or `mvn cargo:run`: ERROR= http://pastie.org/3818540

Comment: I'm not a Faces expert (nor am I fan of Faces). I use Mustache or JSPX.

Comment: Is there a mustache plugin for Roo?

Comment: Not that I know of. I only use Roo for the Domain/Entity scaffolding and not the view scaffolding. Roo does generate JSPX though.